# Solving y'' - 4y = 0 Using Finite Element Analysis(using weak function)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, finite-element-method

**What did I do wrong?please hint.**
i solve this eq similar to bar eq $EA\frac{d^2U}{dx^2}+f=0$. I want to make stiffness matrix Kq=R

> $y''-4y=0, BC1:y(0)=1, BC2:y(1)=2$
>
> 1. Try to the Finite Elements Formulations using Weak form
> 2. Solve the eqation by Finite Element Formulations. Divide elements equally with five nodes.

**1: Weak Formulation**

First, I reformulated the given differential equation by multiplying it with $dx$ and $δy$, resulting in the following integral expression:

$\int_{0}^{1}(y''δy - 4yδy) dx = 0$

I then used integration by parts to transform the integral expression into the following form:

$\left.y'δy\right\rvert_0^1 - \int_{0}^{1}y'δy dx =\int_{0}^{1} 4yδy dx$

but i think δy at x=0 and x=1 is 0. so

$-\int_{0}^{1}y'δy dx =\int_{0}^{1} 4yδy dx$

**2. using shape function(local value)**

To further analyze this equation, I divided the interval [0, 1] into five nodes and expressed y and δy within each element as follows:

$y(s) = as + b$
$δy(s) = as + b$
$x(s) = as + b$

This allows us to represent y(s) as $(1-s)y_1 + sy_2$ and $x(s) as (1-s)x_1 + sx_2$ and δy(s) as $(1-s)δy_1 + sδy_2$. it can change y(s)=$\begin{bmatrix}
1-s & s \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\ y_2
\end{bmatrix} $. δy is same to.

and its derivation

$ \frac{dy}{ds}=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\ y_2
\end{bmatrix}$, $ \frac{dδy}{ds}=\begin{bmatrix}
δy_1 & δy_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\1
\end{bmatrix}$, $\frac{dx}{ds}=x_2-x_1=h$

**3. Substitution**

$\sum_{i=1}^{4} -\int_{i}^{}y'_i δy_i dx =\sum_{i=1}^{4} \int_{i}^{} 4y_iδy dx$

when i=1, $-\int_{0}^{1}\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\ y_2
\end{bmatrix} \frac{1}{h} \begin{bmatrix}
δy_1 & δy_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\1
\end{bmatrix}\frac{1}{h} hds =\int_{0}^{1} 4\begin{bmatrix}
1-s & s \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\ y_2
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
δy_1 & δy_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\1
\end{bmatrix} hds$

it changes to

$\begin{bmatrix}
δy_1 & δy_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
b1 & b2 \\
b3 & b4 \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\y_2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
δy_1 & δy_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
b1 & b2 \\
b3 & b4 \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
y1 \\y2
\end{bmatrix}$

i don't know why $\begin{bmatrix}
y1 \\y2
\end{bmatrix}$ is exist both side.